# The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://ukixe-psg-f15-22.uk.kworld.kpmg.com/' failed with status code '407'." when I use openAI client

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-openai, http-status-code-407

I am trying to use azure open AI service in dotnet core 6.0 application. getting proxy error when I call GetCompletions()

```
var key = "somekey";
            var httpClient = GetProxyHttpclient(_configuration);
            //OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri("https://azopenaikk.openai.azure.com/"),new AzureKeyCredential(key));

            string endpoint = "https://azopenaikait.openai.azure.com/";
            var client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri(endpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());

            string deploymentName = "text-davinci-003";
            string prompt = "What is Azure OpenAI?";
            Console.Write($"Input: {prompt}");

            Response<Completions> completionsResponse = client.GetCompletions(deploymentName, prompt);
            string completion = completionsResponse.Value.Choices[0].Text;
            Console.WriteLine($"Chatbot: {completion}");
```

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced this issue with few modifications and it worked for me***

I have referred [ms docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cognitive-services/openai/includes/dotnet.md) and used the below modified code which gave me result.

**`Code`**

```
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;
using Azure;

var key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

string endpoint = "Your endpoint";
var client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(key));

string deploymentName = "Your deployment name";
string prompt = "What is Azure OpenAI?";
Console.WriteLine($"Input: {prompt}");

Response<Completions> completionsResponse = await client.GetCompletionsAsync(deploymentName, prompt);
string completion = completionsResponse.Value.Choices[0].Text;
Console.WriteLine($"Chatbot: {completion}");
```

**`Output`**

[image]